# Core Data - Fetched Property with bitmasks and abstract entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, fetched-property

[image: Core Data Editor displaying situation]

(Data models renamed to preserve anonymity.  :D )

So, I have a situation where on a Thing, whose configuration is defined by its own special object, though that object can be one of 2 class types.

I would like to be able to do Fetch Requests on this model by asking if the Thing's Configuration is of a certain known subclass, and if so, does it have a few specific flags set in its bitmask.  If this is true, I define this as being "not special".  Therefore, if it also has the other type of subclass as it's Configuration, it is also "not special".

My questions are these:

- Have I got my syntax right?  (In my app I get faults)
- Why does it want to return an NSArray?  (I thought its traversing a to-one relationship on a single object.  How would I therefore interpret this NSArray?)

I should add that I only know Core Data via MagicalRecord more or less.  And I use mogenerator too.

Comment: A little vague and hard to understand, but let's try to discuss the relationship. If your [thing.configuration isKindOfClass:SpecialConfiguration] then it has a bitmask, and can be not special. You want to create a fetch request that will fetch all Things where [thing.configuration isKindOfClass:SpecialConfiguration] && thing.configuration.bitmask && 1, or [thing.configuration isKindOfClass:StandardConfiguration].

Comment: a NSFetchRequest always returns an array, so it will return an array of Things even if there's one. Was that the second question?

Comment: @mitrenegade - yes, and yes! You understood perfectly.  Have to be a bit vague on purpose, but that is the relationship.  Except I thought a fetched property belongs to an instance of Thing and is not a fetch for all Things?

So, the question is have I got that right?

Comment: haha unfortunately i havent used fetch property much. i'll play around with it on my system when i get a chance. hopefully someone else will chime in too. have you just tried it and seen if it works?

Comment: It would be great if CoreData had a console and sandbox mode much like Ruby so you could just query and debug your models without having to write an app